# SQL: Using IIF with CASE Statements in MS Access to fill a column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to know how or if it's possible to use IIF statements in a CASE Statement when writing SQL code for MS Access. I'm trying to fill a single column based on other columns' inputs.

I've already tried it by writing the below code and by looking into how CASE statements can be used in MS Access.

```
RE020_STATUS: 
CASE 
WHEN IIf([03_RE]![RE060_ACTUAL] Is Null,"Pending RE060",IIf([03_RE]![RE097_ACTUAL] Is Null,"Pending RE097",IIf([04_CI001_CI091]![CI050_ACTUAL] Is Null,"Pending CI050",IIf([04_CI001_CI091]![CI081_ACTUAL] Is Null,"Pending CI081",IIf([01_JobDetails_JI_CL]![CL001_ACTUAL] Is Null,"Pending CL001",IIf([01_JobDetails_JI_CL]![CL100_ACTUAL] Is Null,"Pending CL100",IIf([05_CI093_CI164]![CI139_ACTUAL] Is Null,"Pending CI139",IIf([05_CI093_CI164]![CI140_ACTUAL] Is Null,"Pending CI140","Pending CL101")))))))) 
WHEN IIf([03_RE]![RE020_FORECAST] Is Null,IIf([01_JobDetails_JI_CL]![CL001_ACTUAL] Is Null,"Pending CL001",IIf([01_JobDetails_JI_CL]![CL100_ACTUAL] Is Null,"Pending CL100",IIf([05_CI093_CI164]![CI139_ACTUAL] Is Null,"Pending CI139",IIf([05_CI093_CI164]![CI140_ACTUAL] Is Null,"Pending CI140","Pending CL101"))))) 
END
```

So far all I get are errors about how the code is written, that I'm missing an operand, expression or statement.

Comment: Access does not support CASE in SQL statements. Use IIf() or Switch() or Choose() functions without CASE.

Comment: Can I use nested IIf statements within a SWITCH Statement? I'm just trying to find a a way to code this all in 1 new column, not 2 new columns.

Comment: Yes, can nest within SWITCH. Sounds like really should build a VBA function.